# Where to farm rank 3 Monster Materials?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I thought Chocolina sold them but she doesn't. Maybe because I didn't finish the game?

I need the materials for my Chichu but I can't find them!

Answer (score 5):

Chocolina stops selling the potent monster materials after the first grade. She does, however, start selling *Power Orbs*, *Mana Orbs*, *Vitality Orbs* when you get to *Academia -500 AF-*, but that's towards the end of the game.

Here's where you can farm the materials:

#### Potent orbs

- Buccaboos in the *Stonestump Wastelands* and *Grave Ridge* areas of the *Archlyte Steppe -??? AF-* when it's sunny
- Ghouls in *Academia -400 AF-*, but only before you reach New Town<sup>2</sup>
- Garganzolae and Apotamkins in *A Dying World -700 AF-*<sup>1</sup>
- Winning the *Orphan Derby*, *Lindzei Cup*, or *Pulse Cup* in the Fal'Cie class Chocobo races at *Serendipity -??? AF-*

#### Potent engines

- Flans in *Augusta Tower -300 AF-*, but not on Floor 13
- Munchkins<sup>1</sup> in the *Bresha Ruins -300 AF-*

#### Vitality orbs

- Miquiztli in *Academia -500 AF-*
- Vodianoi and Samovira in the southern portion of the *Grave Ridge* region in the *Archlyte Steppe -??? AF-* when it's cloudy
- Bunkerbeasts in *Yaschas Massif -100 AF-*
- Green Chocobos in the *-1XX AF-* eras of *Yaschas Massif*
- Winning the *Atomos Derby*<sup>1</sup> in the Fal'Cie class Chocobo races at *Serendipity -??? AF-*

#### Vitality engines

- Zwerg Metrodroids<sup>1</sup> in *Augusta Tower -200 AF-*

#### Power orbs

- Tonberries that appear in rifts in the *Brescha Ruins -300 AF-*
- Buccaboos in the *Stonestump Wastelands* and *Grave Ridge* areas of the *Archlyte Steppe -??? AF-* when it's sunny
- Pitterpatters in *Yaschas Massif -100 AF-*
- Barbed Specters in the *Stonestump Wastelands* and *Grave Ridge* areas of the *Archlyte Steppe -??? AF-* when it's cloudy
- Winning the *Carbuncle Classic*<sup>1</sup> in the Fal'Cie class Chocobo races at *Serendipity -??? AF-*

#### Power engines

- Yaksha and Yakshini<sup>1</sup> in the *Vile Peaks -010 AF-*
- Shaguma and Haguma<sup>1</sup> in the *Vile Peaks -010 AF-*

#### Mana orbs

- Xolotl in *Academia -500 AF-*
- Sahagin Princes in the *Assembly Area* region of the *Sunleth Waterscape -300 AF-* after completing the main story events
- Winning the *Anima Stakes*<sup>1</sup> in the Fal'Cie class Chocobo races at *Serendipity -??? AF-*

#### Mana engines

- Vespid Solders<sup>1</sup> in *Augusta Tower -200 AF-* mostly on the 51st floor

---

<sup>Note 1:</sup> My personal farming recommendations: they tend to have far better yields or are more mindlessly farmable than the alternatives.

<sup>Note 2:</sup> They'll show up again if you close the gate.

Comment: Would you say it's always better to use the **Potent** materials over the more focused ones?

Comment: @Yuck (revising my comment from before) Potent is good for *most* situations, but not all: better to use vitality materials for sentinels, which don't benefit from magic or strength but benefit greatly from HP. And I've found using the mana/power materials when a ravager or commando is in a high-growth period more beneficial than potent materials.

Answer (score 1):

Just about everything *A Dying World -700 AF-* Drops potent orbs. The only monsters that do not are the untameable Cie'th monsters.