# Where to find specific monster items

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where to farm rank 3 Monster Materials?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49932/where-to-farm-rank-3-monster-materials)

I am finding that I'm running out of grade 3 monster items really fast. Does anyone know where I can go to farm some of these items?

Or better yet, is there a listing online somewhere of which items are available where?

I primarily need grade 3 organic items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Chocolina stops selling the potent monster materials after the first grade.
>
> Potent orbs, the all-around organic grade 3 material, can be found off of:
>
> Buccaboos in the Archlyte Steppe -??? AF-
>     Ghouls in Academia -400 AF-
>    Garganzolae and Apotamkins in A Dying World -700 AF-
>
> Potent engines, the all-around mechanical grade 3 material, can be found off of:
>
> Flans in Augusta Tower -300 AF-
>    Munchkins in the Bresha Ruins -300 AF-
>
> If you're into the specialized—but lesser—monster materials, Chocolina does start selling Power Orbs, Mana Orbs, Vitality Orbs when you get to Academia -500 AF-.